# Editing Finder Favorites

Tags: macos, finder

I am trying to edit one of the names of a Favorite in the Favorites List in Finder. In most parts of OSX, one can simply position the cursor to the name and and editing box opens up, but not here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to right click on the favorite and "get info". The name shows up under "Name and Extension". You'll not, I think, be able to rename everything. If it's greyed out, for example, you won't be able to rename it.